# WiX: RemoveFile declaration removes files only on install

Tags: wix

I have the following code snippet in my wxs file. No matter I put the On attribute to be both or uninstall it does not remove the files with trace extension from the Trace folder. It works fine only on installation. If I change only the On attribute to be both or install it works on installation, but never works on uninstallation process whether it is both or uninstall.

```
<Directory Id="TRACEDIR" Name="Trace">
    <Component Id="Trace" Guid="*" KeyPath="yes">
        <RemoveFile Id="RemTraceFiles" On="both" Name="*.trace"/>
    </Component>
</Directory>
```

Any ideas, please?

I didn't create another bug for the following question, rather, I added it below, since I believe, it may have some connection to the above one. It might be the same reason for both cases to fail. So my second question is about the following scenario in the same file, however, this time it is a folder removal, not just a file removal. Assume we have:

```
<Property Id="LOGDIREX">
    <DirectorySearch Id="CheckLogDir" Path="[INSTALLDIR]\Log" Depth="1" AssignToProperty="yes" />
</Property>

...  

<Directory Id="LOGDIR" Name="Log">
    <Component Id="Log" Guid="01978736-614F-46C1-88FA-056284510164">
        <!--RemoveFolder Id='LogFolder' On='both' /-->
        <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\FoobarLog' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
        <utilExt:RemoveFolderEx Id='LogFolder' On='both' Property='LOGDIREX'/>
    </Component>
</Directory>
```

So in this example if I use the RemoveFolderEx tag declaration of the UtilExtension library then the Log folder under my installation directory gets deleted on both, install and uninstall, processes. But if I comment the RemoveFolderEx declaration and uncomment to use the regular Wix RemoveFolder as declared right above RemoveFolderEx declaration then it doesn't delete the Log folder neither on install nor on uninstall process.

Any ideas?

And just to mention that both Directory declarations, TRACEDIR and LOGDIR, in this question are declared under the INSTALLDIR which is some directory for my application.

Answer (score 0):

TRACEDIR is a custom property, and I assume you believe that the values of properties are somehow saved between the install and the uninstall, but they are not. That means you need to preserve and restore the value of TRACEDIR, and the WiX "Remember Property" pattern is probably what you need.

http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/

Also note that a directorysearch for INSTALLDIR is likely to fail because that search takes place very early in the install, and it's not clear that INSTALLDIR has a valid value.

Also, you can create a verbose log of the uninstall to see where your property is being set (or not) using system logging policy, or:

msiexec /x {productcode} /L*VX [path to log file]

should also work.

Comment: I renamed the TRACEDIR into MYTRACEDIR - the same behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure why a name change is relevant. Did you use the "remember property" pattern on properties that you need at uninstall time/?

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought you were saying TRACEDIR is a special key name for Wix like the TARGETDIR is, that's why I renamed it. Anyway, I then followed your advice and declared a REMEMBERME property like it is in the link you provided. I used that in my RegistryValue declaration along with my RemoveFolder declaration for the LOGDIR component. It didn't work.

I was a bit skeptical about testing it for TRACEDIR as well since it holds RemoveFile declaration and not a RemoveFolder as LOGDIR does. However, I tested it with TRACEDIR and it didn't work either.